# Captcha unification mechanism in different browsers?

Tags: firefox, browser, internet-explorer, browser-cache, captcha

How the captchas which are generated from one site could be valid at the same time but in 2 different browsers (e.g. IE and FF)? What makes this separation? How I can find these values or factors?

I think my connection IP is same in both but I can enter website from both of browsers simultaneously.

I had been searched a lot but have not found anything.

Comment: Are they both showing the same captcha?

Comment: of course not, different captcha from same source, but each one is valid and you can enter into the website by answering each one.

Comment: You need to add to your queston what you think should be happening, but isn't. Are you asking why they are not the same? Captcha is just a mechanism to block robots, and should load a different query each time the webpage is loaded. From which browser does not matter.

Comment: I mean that "What makes this ability to valid 2 different Captchas from same website in 2 different browsers (e.g. IE and FF) at the same time? and what does not do that in 2 different windows of a browser (e.g. IE or FF)?"